# How to configure external library with own dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I created new library by following this [post](https://medium.com/stantmob/how-to-use-android-libraries-locally-and-leaving-your-development-more-fast-47ef921c6dd9).

So I have library project (**library**) and app project (**app**). 
When I manually connect library to application with following code, it works.

```
include ':libraryname'
project(':libraryname').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../your-library-folder/libraryname')
```

**But it is working only until I add new AAR dependency into library**

File - New Module - New AAR package and also I add dependency (implementation project(':library_aar')) into **library**.

After I do this, Android Studio shows me error (for **app**, inside **library** everything looks ok):
**Project with path ':library_aar' could not be found in project ':library'.**

**Working:**

```
Project Application
 - Module "app" > dependency to "library"

Project Library
 - Module "library"
```

**Not working:**

```
Project Application
 - Module "app" > dependency to "library"

Project Library
 - Module "library" > dependency to "library_aar"
 - Module "library_aar"
```

Question is how to properly setup internal library dependency on some AAR library?

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove from library module dependency `implementation project(':library_arr')` because you want to implement library project inside app module so why u implementing in library module

Comment: Maybe I didn´t explain it well, but let me clarify. I want to use library as external dependency for my application, but inside library I need dependency to other module (AAR), becuase without it library will not be able provide required functionality.

Comment: @Michalsx For what I understand is that you want to let other users ise your dependency(just assume that you want to let the users implement library like most big companies like `firebase` let you add my using `implementation 'library-name'`) So what they do is that they host their files on github server. Now after you have made the library, right click and select `create Gits`. But you should have GitHub account

Comment: @Gourav No, I don´t want this. I have my application and this application (as other my applications) will use functionality from library. But first I have to implement functionality and I don´t want to implement it in library without application (without using connection to library from app), I want to implement it in library from my application (when I have working connection to library from app). I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Made more difficult now :( Please join me in a chat room and we will discuss there

Comment: Join here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186183/library-talk

Comment: @Gourav Please check updated description with depedency schema.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, I had to also add dependency for "library_aar" to "app".

```
Project Application
 - Module "app" > dependency to "library"
 - Module "app" > dependency to "library_aar"

Project Library
 - Module "library" > dependency to "library_aar"
 - Module "library_aar"
```